# How show decimal point in viewbag razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I defined a Viewbag in .cshtml file as

```
ViewBag.version = "2.0";
```

but when I get the value:

```
alert(@ViewBag.version.ToString());
```

It shows as 2, it takes out .0 after

Comment: Try putting quotes around it. The rendered JS is `alert(2.0)` which will of course alert just the integer part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `General Grievance` said,`@ViewBag.version.ToString()` will be `Number`,so you can use `''`.

```
alert('@ViewBag.version.ToString()');
```

Also you can try to convert it to float and formats the number using fixed-point notation.

```
alert(parseFloat(@ViewBag.version.ToString()).toFixed(1));
```

Comment: Well, it's going to be a `Number`, not `int` since it's JS. And the `.ToString()` is unnecessary since it's already a C# string. Razor is a confusing mess sometimes, which is why I try to leave as much JS out of it as possible.